# any way to know the page height using only css

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, print-css

I have a code something like this

```
 <table class = "narr_table"> 
    <tr>
      <td> 
            <span> Text 1 </span>
            <span> helper text </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
   ..
   </table>
```

I changed the span elements display as block elements, as I want those to be displayed one below another.

The two span elements should go together in the print media in IE 7 at all zoom levels, and only by using CSS.

I tried page-break-before:avoid and page-break-after:avoid but no luck.

So, I would like to know if we can identify the height of the page using css and move the element to the next page if the current div exceeds the page length ?

here is the css I used:

```
    .narr_table tr td span
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .narr_table tr td  span:first-child 
    {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }

    .narr_table tr td span:first-child + span
    {
        page-break-before: avoid;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try for no page break inside of that td instead

Comment: page-break-inside:avoid will only work for IE8+.